# How to delete \ from a text?

Tags: python-2.7

I need to delete \ from a text. For instance, if the input is as below:

if the executive\\'s employment terminates due to disability, the executive will receive payment majority of the directors then in office.\', \'5% of the amount paid to the executive pursuant to (i)(c) above), (v)

How can I delete \\ from \\'s and \ from \'? I tried to do some ways but they don't work.

```
q4 = re.sub(r'\*','',q3)
```

Comment: Are you sure your text actually has backslashes in it? More likely, you're confusing the `repr` representation with the actual string contents. Try `print`ing it and see what happens.

Comment: (Even if it turns out your string does have backslashes in it, you'll need to learn about what backslashes in a string literal mean, because your regex attempt isn't escaping the backslash.)

Comment: I tried using PRint and it still shows \. I just want to delete it from the text so that the text is easier to read. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
nobackslashes = withbackslashes.replace('\\', '')
```

You don't need anything as sophisticated as regexes; ordinary string replacement works fine. The important thing is to escape the backslash; in a string literal, a backslash represents the start of an escape sequence, generally used to put untypeable characters into a string. Two backslashes is the escape sequence for a literal backslash character.

Once you do this, if you still see backslashes, you're probably displaying the string in a way that adds an extra layer of escaping. For example, if you make a file with the contents

```
O'Connor says, "Hi."
```

and view the contents in an interactive interpreter session:

```
>>> with open('asdf.txt') as f:
...     text = f.read()
...
>>> text
'O\'Connor says, "Hi."'
```

you'll see a backslash, because Python is showing you a string literal that would produce a string with the same contents, rather than printing the string's characters directly. On the other hand, if you use `print`:

```
>>> print text
O'Connor says, "Hi."
```

that doesn't happen.